# Why Python running on Intel rather than Apple?

Tags: pytorch, apple-m1

I am running a Python program that uses Torch. I'm using the Torch nightly build (which supports MPS/M1) and putting my tensors on `mps`, indicating that the M1 processor is being used as a GPU. However, Activity Monitor lists the "Kind" of my Python process as "Intel" rather than "Apple" (see image).

I am assuming this slows down my program. Any clue why this is happening, and how I can make sure Python runs as "Apple" rather than "Intel?
[image: Screenshot from Activity Monitor]

I confirmed that the GPU is being used (via Activity Monitor), and that my tensors are on MPS (rather than CPU or CUDA). I expected the program kind to be "Apple", but it is "Intel" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the Python program with the arch argument if you want it to run on the M1 CPU rather than the Intel processor:

```
python -m arch -arch arm64 my_program.py
```

The Intel CPU will be used if software needs functionality that the M1 processor does not provide. The maximum size of integers that the Python interpreter can handle may be checked using the `sys.maxsize` property to see if the M1 processor is in use. The Python interpreter is operating on a 32-bit architecture, which may not be optimal for the M1 CPU, if the value is less than 2^63-1. You might try utilizing a 64-bit Python interpreter in this situation.

Comment: Thanks! I installed `arch` and am using it to run my program as you specified, and am getting `No module named arch.__main__; 'arch' is a package and cannot be directly executed`

Comment: `pip install arch`

then run application with

`python -m arch my_program.py`

Comment: I get the same error message. MWE:  `echo "print('Ok!')" > temp.py; python -m arch temp.py`

Comment: I'm confused. Is this the package you suggest I install? It looks to be something with econometrics... https://pypi.org/project/arch/